# saving and retrieving data from database using TinyMICE

Tags: jquery, asp.net, tinymce

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        mode: "exact",
        theme: "modern",
        editor_selector: "elm1",
        encoding: "xml",
        menubar: "false",
        plugins: ["textcolor "],
        toolbar1: " bold italic | print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons"
    });
</script>
```

Textbox:

```
<textarea id="elm1" name="elm1" rows="15" cols="80" style="width: 80%" runat="server"></textarea>
```

While i am saving the data it is showing :

```
<p>Hi i am <strong>Shawn</strong></p> at text editor
```

and in data base :

```
&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;Hi i am &amp;lt;strong&amp;gt;Shawn&amp;lt;/strong&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
```

While Retreving from data base it is showing

```
 <p>Hi i am <strong>Shawn</strong></p> at text editor
```

I just want to get it in exact html format as it is shown while editing:

Hi i am **Shawn**

Comment: Isn't that already the exact format? you just have to append it again.

Comment: no it is not, i want the text to be formatted like in the last line